# Fixing Rate in Quantlib

Tags: interest-rates, quantlib

While pricing Interest Rate Swap, I am providing Fixing rate for historical date using "addFixing(date, value)" function. But when I am trying to change value it is not happening and picking up old value only, giving following error:

"RuntimeError: At least one duplicated fixing provided: January 23rd, 2018, 0.017453 while 0.017452 value is already present"

Is there a way to change this fixing rate?

Answer (score 1):

`addFixing`has a third parameter `forceOverwrite` which is `false` by default.  Calling `addFixing(date, value, true)` will allow the change.

On Python, the third parameter is not exported (you might open an issue on GitHub to fix that). You'll have to go for the nuclear option:

```
IndexManager.instance().clearHistory(index.name())
```

will clear the whole history of fixings and allow you to reload it.

Comment: I tried this but getting error again: 

index.addFixing(Date(23,1,2018),0.017453, True) 

TypeError: addFixing() takes 3 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: So you're on Python?

Comment: Yes, on Python...

Comment: See the update.

Comment: Thanks Luigi...created GitHub issue for same https://github.com/lballabio/QuantLib-SWIG/issues/110. And using nuclear option as of now.